# SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 - Change export file name

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-pdf

I'm planning a upgrade to SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services from 2012.

In version 2012, which my company has been using for several years, we added a extension 
which abled us to modify the filename when the user exports reports to PDF, Excel,...
So instead of having e.g. the filename StudentReport.PDF, we get StudentReport_Student_Name.PDF.

To manage this we added a hidden field into the footer of each report, FileNameExtend=[[Student Name]] in white text so
you don't see it unless you change the color of text.

Then the following JavaScript code was added to ReportingServices.js on the server.

```
function ModifyExportUrlBase() {
    var rv = null;
    var r = null;
    try {
        rv = this.$find("ctl31");
        r = rv._getInternalViewer();
    }
    catch (err) {
        setTimeout(ModifyExportUrlBase, 1000)
        return;
    }
    if (r != null && r.ExportUrlBase != null) {
        // Search for FileNameExtension in all div elements
        var fileNameExtend = function () {
            var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            var result = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
                if (divElements[i].innerText.indexOf("FileNameExtend=[[") > -1 && divElements[i].innerText.indexOf("]]") > -1) {
                    var istart = divElements[i].innerText.indexOf("[[");
                    var istop = divElements[i].innerText.indexOf("]]");
                    result = divElements[i].innerText.substring(istart + 2, istop);
                }
            }
            return String(result);
        }();

        // Change ExportUrlBase if fileNameExtend exist
        if (fileNameExtend != null && fileNameExtend.length > 0) {
            var url = r.ExportUrlBase;
            var i = url.indexOf("FileName=");
            var j = url.indexOf("&", i + 1);
            var fileName = url.substring(i, j) + '_' + encodeURI(fileNameExtend);
            r.ExportUrlBase = r.ExportUrlBase.substring(0, i) + fileName + r.ExportUrlBase.substring(j, r.ExportUrlBase.length);
        }
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(ModifyExportUrlBase, 1000);
    }
}
ModifyExportUrlBase();
```

Reporting Service 2017 seems to be implemented in quite different way than 2012.
Has any one found a way to implement this functionality?